# Flattening a One to many Join to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am trying to achieve a result in SQL but struggling to get it to work correctly.

Table A contains a list of Appt Numbers along with other data
Table B contains a list of Items provided at the Appt

Table A Appt

| ApptID | ApptDate | ApptUser | ApptCustomer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/2024 | JONESA1 | Mr John Jenkins |
| 2 | 09/02/2024 | SMITHA1 | Mrs Gemma Robinson |

Table B SuppliedGoods

| ID | ApptID | SuppliedGoodsName | SuppliedGoodsCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Drawing Pencil | 0001 |
| 2 | 1 | Fountain Pen | 0003 |
| 3 | 1 | Ruler 30CM | 0007 |
| 4 | 2 | Fountain Pen | 0003 |
| 5 | 2 | Pencil Rubber | 0010 |

The result I am trying to achieve is to join the two tables so that I get the following:

| ApptID | ApptDate | SuppliedGoodsName | SuppliedGoodsName | SuppliedGoodsName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/2024 | Drawing Pencil | Fountain Pen | Ruler 30CM |
| 2 | 09/02/2024 | Fountain Pen | Pencil Rubber | NULL |

I've tried the basic joins with with inner etc but that just gives multiple rows:

```
SELECT A.APPTID, 
A.APPTDATE,
B.SUPPLIEDGOODSNAME

FROM APPT A
INNER JOIN SUPPLIEDGOODS B ON A.ID = B.APPTID
```

| ApptID | ApptDate | SuppliedGoods |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/2024 | Drawing Pencil |
| 1 | 01/02/2024 | Fountain Pen |
| 1 | 01/02/2024 | Ruler 30CM |
| 2 | 09/02/2024 | Fountain Pen |
| 2 | 09/02/2024 | Pencil Rubber |

I do not wish to the the 'STRING_AGG' function as want each of the goods to be within their own cell/field.

Group By fails as not all the fields are included in the aggregate function.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) `A` *is* a good alias for `APPT`, but `B` is for `SUPPLIEDGOODS`? There aren't any `B`s in `SUPPLIEDGOODS`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @thomA. I have actually changed the data just to use for an example as my data is more difficult to understand. So wouldn't generally use A and B but thank you for the tip.